# C: Why isn't size_t a C keyword?

Tags: c, types, sizeof, size-t

`sizeof` is a C *keyword*. It returns the size in a type named `size_t`. However, `size_t` is **not** a keyword, but is defined primarily in **`stddef.h`** and probably other C standard header files too.

Consider a scenario where you want to create a C program which **does not** include any C standard headers or libraries. (Like for example, if you are creating an OS kernel.) Now, in such code, `sizeof` can be used (it is a C keyword, so it is a part of the *language*), but the type that it returns (`size_t`) is not available!

Does not this signify some kind of a problem in the C standard specification? Can you clarify this?

Comment: Many headers are perfectly safe and sensible to include, even in an OS kernel. The issue you are worried about in a kernel is linking to libraries, not including headers.

Comment: RBerteig: Just for argument sake, let's say I want to create a C program using just the language, no headers/libraries and I want to use sizeof.

Comment: You'd need to write your own implementation library in assembly, most likely. You can't do an awful lot without the headers and libraries (and their associated functions).

Comment: Standard headers are part of the language. Many do define the interfaces to the standard libraries, and there are good reasons not to use those in a kernel or deep embedded system. But others primarily define useful things related to the implementation: stddef.h, limits.h are examples.

Comment: Chris and RBerteig: Yes, but let's consider a program which doesn't use any headers/libraries, just does some arithmetic say.

Comment: @Ash - How are you going to tell whoever runs the program what the answer is? Where are you going to get the input numbers from?

Comment: Chris Lutz: That is moot, this is just a debate to map the precise details of the C language :-)

Comment: @Ash: it is not at all moot. Without routines such as printf how is your C program going to return any data?

Comment: printf has nothing to do with returning data. Your entire program could run and do stuff without ever needing to get user input or output, and whatever he wants the program to do could be defined in custom libraries. Not that this is sensible in most cases... it's just for the sake of the argument.

Comment: Also note that even if you only do arithmetic, the compiler will generate function calls to functions provided by its runtime. This is why nearly all C code compiled by GCC depends on libgcc.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It does not literally return a value of type size_t since size_t is not a concrete type in itself, but rather a typedef to an unspecified built-in type. Typedef identifiers (such as size_t) are completely equivalent to their respective underlying types (and are converted thereto at compile time). If size_t is defined as an unsigned int on your platform, then sizeof returns an unsigned int when it is compiled on your system. size_t is just a handy way of maintaining portability and only needs to be included in stddef.h if you are using it explicitly by name.

Comment: +1, the right answer. Anything that returns a typedef cannot really be said to return that typedef. It returns whatever the typedef boils down to. If you want portability, include stddef.h. If you don't, look up the definition of size_t on your platform and use that type directly instead.

Comment: Volte: I'm seeing the picture now. So, the compiler cannot "see" size_t, but use a type for sizeof that is exactly the same as what size_t is typedef to in the headers that ship with the compiler.

Comment: As pointed out in my answer, the compiler did "see" the typedef of size)t when it itself was compiled - in a sense it "knows" about size_t

Comment: Neil Butterworth: I couldn't grok it in your reply, but understood it when I read Volte's reply :-) Now to complicate matters a bit, what will happen with a cross compiler whose native and destination platforms require different size_t? ;-)

Comment: The size_t that the compiler saw is at best an implementation detail since conforming C compilers could be written in any language. It is a matter of standard that sizeof's return type is equivalent to size_t, but the actual underlying type is left to the implementation of the compiler.

Comment: @Neil You're not just wrong in this case, you're categorically wrong.

Answer (score 14):

`sizeof` is a keyword because, despite it's name and usage, it is an *operator* like `+` or `=` or `<` rather than a *function* like `printf()` or `atoi()` or `fgets()`. A lot of people forget (or just don't know) that `sizeof` is actually an operator, and is *always* resolved at compile-time rather than at runtime.

The C language doesn't need `size_t` to be a usable, consistent language. That's just part of the standard library. The C language needs all operators. If, instead of `+`, C used the keyword `plus` to add numbers, you would make it an operator.

Besides, I do semi-implicit recasting of `size_t`s to `unsigned int`s (and regular `int`s, but Kernighan and Ritchie will someday smite me for this) all the time. You can assign the return type of a `sizeof` to an int if you like, but in my work I'm usually just passing it straight on to a `malloc()` or something.

Comment: Chris: Thanks for that cogent explanation. But, doesn't that imply that size_t is intimately inside C, like int/char is. Why define it in a header then?

Comment: Not that it's widely used (or even supported), but for C99-style variable length arrays, sizeof is evaluated at runtime.

Comment: @Michael - Seriously? Damn. However, C99 is really poorly supported, so I'm sticking to my malloc() and realloc() and free() to do that job for a while.

Comment: Michael Burr: That is news to me! Thanks for pointing it out :-)

Comment: @ChrisLutz Since when is C99 poorly supported? This is news to me. It's not because MSVC fails to implement a standard that is more than a decade old, that that standard is poorly supported...

Comment: @rubenvb - Since 4 years ago when I wrote that comment. :P In the intervening time since those four years, I came across the opinion that VLAs should be avoided anyway due to inability to check for stack overflow; and since THAT time, C11 has been finalized and I don't know if they fixed that problem. Either way, `malloc`/`free` always works, if you can take the overhead.

Comment: @ChrisLutz: C11 fixed the problem by making VLA support optional.  IMHO, the proper right approach would have been to have a pair of macro which was like alloca, but worked as an allocate/release pair, with a requirement that an allocation within a block must be matched by a release within that block.  Implementations that would be unable to support alloca-style semantics could define the allocate/release functions as synonyms for malloc/free, but those that could support stack-based semantics could improve performance and reduce fragmentation.

Answer (score 9):

Some headers from the C standard are defined for a *freestanding* environment, i.e. fit for use e.g. in an operating system kernel. They do not define any functions, merely defines and typedefs.

They are float.h, iso646.h, limits.h, stdarg.h, stdbool.h, stddef.h and stdint.h.

When working on an operating system, it isn't a bad idea to start with *these* headers. Having them available makes many things easier in your kernel. Especially stdint.h will become handy (uint32_t et al.).

Comment: DevSolar: OS kernel was just an example, instead consider a case where I want to write a C program using sizeof, but not including any C header. Thanks for the info about the freestanding environment headers, I wasn't aware of that.

Answer (score 8):

> Does not this signify some kind of a problem in the C standard specification?

Look up the difference between a hosted implementation of C and a freestanding C implementation.  The freestanding (C99) implementation is required to provide headers:

- `<float.h>`
- `<iso646.h>`
- `<limits.h>`
- `<stdarg.h>`
- `<stdbool.h>`
- `<stddef.h>`
- `<stdint.h>`

These headers do not define any functions at all.  They define parts of the language that are somewhat compiler specific (for example, the `offsetof` macro in `<stddef.h>`, and the variable argument list macros and types in `<stdarg.h>`), but they can be handled without actually being built into the language as full keywords.

This means that even in your hypothetical kernel, you should expect the C compiler to provide these headers and any underlying support functions - even though you provide everything else.

Answer (score 4):

I think that the main reasons that `size_t` is not a keyword are:

- there's no compelling reason for it to be.  The designers of the C and C++ languages have always preferred to have language features be implemented in the library if possible and reasonable
- adding keywords to a language can create problems for an existing body of legacy code. This is another reason they are generally resistant to adding new keywords.

For example, in discussing the next major revision of the C++ standard, [Stroustrup had this to say](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/cpp0x.html):

> The C++0x improvements should be done in such a way that the resulting language is easier to learn and use. Among the rules of thumb for the committee are:
>
> `...`
>
> - Prefer standard library facilities to language extensions
>
> `...`

Comment: Still, it feels quite weird that a built-in operator `sizeof` yields an expression of a library type `size_t`. :)

Comment: @musiphil: it might feel less weird to think of it as: the library must define `size_t` to be the type that the `sizeof` operator yields.

Answer (score 3):

There is no reason not to include stddef.h, even if you are working on a kernel - it defines type sizes for your specific compiler that any code will need.

Note also that almost all C compilers are self-compiled. The actual compiler code for the sizeof operator will therefore use size_t and reference the same stddef.h file as does user code.

Comment: Neil: But just for argument sake, let's say I want to create a program that doesn't use any C standard headers or libraries. Just a pure C language program.

Comment: The header files are _part_ of the C language!

Comment: Neil Butterworth: I couldn't grok it in your reply, but understood it when I read Volte's reply :-) Now to complicate matters a bit, what will happen with a cross compiler whose native and destination platforms require different size_t? ;-)

Answer (score 2):

size_t is actually a type - often an unsigned int. Sizeof is an operator that gives the size of a type. The type returned by sizeof is actually implementation-specific, not a C standard. It's just an integer.

Edit:
To be very clear, you do not need the size_t type in order to use sizeof. I think the answer you're looking for is - Yes, it is inconsistent. However, **it doesn't matter.** You can still practically use sizeof correctly without having a size_t definition from a header file.

Comment: Anthony: I'm aware of that. But, size_t is defined in C headers, it's not a part of the language. That's where the disconnect is.

Comment: in the c++ standard at least (I don't have the C standard) sizeof is defined as returning size_t not just an integer type, and the clause explicitly referenced stddef.h

Comment: Ash: The following code is valid:

int main() {
double a;
unsigned int b = sizeof(a);
}

Without any headers, this is still correct. The lowest common denominator of size_t is that it is an unsigned integral type. Size_t is basically just a typedef.

Comment: Anthony Kanago: This might also imply that the compiler you're using is aware of size_t. If we get pedantic, this may not be a valid case since the standard doesn't say the compiler should know about size_t.

Answer (score 2):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4s7x1k91(VS.71).aspx):

> When the sizeof operator is applied
>   to an object of type char, it yields 1

Even if you don't have stddef.h available/included and don't know about size_t, using sizeof you can get the size of objects relative to char.

Comment: But if you want to store that size somewhere, without risking overflow, you  will need the typedef of size_t.

Comment: schnaader: All that says is that size_t will be some sort of an integral type, but not exactly what type.

Comment: @Neil - Honestly, how often do you find a type for which sizeof() returns something that would overflow even an unsigned char? On my system, even a FILE struct is only 88 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

**size_t** is not a keyword by necessity. Different architectures often have different sizes for integral types. For example a 64 bit machine is likely to have an **unsigned long long** as **size_t** if they didn't decide to make **int** a 64 bit datatype.

If you make sizeof a builtin type to the compiler, then it will take away the power to do cross compilation.

Also, **sizeof** is more like a magic compile time macro (think c++ template) which explains why it is a keyword instead of defined type.

Comment: This argument is moot since even the size of integral types (for example) change depending on the platform. An int could be 4 bytes or 8 bytes and so on, but int is still a keyword.

Answer (score 1):

The simple reason is because it is not a fundamental type. If you look up the C standard you will find that fundamental types include `int`, `char` etc but not `size_t`. Why so? As others have already pointed out, `size_t` is an implementation specific type (i.e. a type capable of holding the size in number of "C bytes" of any object).

On the other hand, `sizeof` is an (unary) operator. All operators are keywords.

Comment: Which fundamental type is NOT implementation-specific? That `size_t` is an implementation-specific type cannot be the reason for its being a library type.