# difference(s) between size_t and sizeof

Tags: c, performance

What are  the differences  between,

```
malloc ( sizeof ( char ) * N )
```

and

```
size_t datalen = N 
malloc ( datalen  )
```

Where  should  we use `size_t` instead of `sizeof ( char )` and vice versa?

Are there any performance difference between `size_t` and `sizeof ( char )`?

Comment: The difference: `sizeof(char)` is always one. `size_t` is a type.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is one lame way to get a `1` having type `size_t`...

Comment: @R.. `sizeof(char)` is not a lame way of getting 1. I do not know of systems which has char more than 1 byte but this has been the case for `int` data type which adds to the portability of your code. Moreover writing this add generalness to your program(it may look odd that you do it for `int` and not for `char`)

Comment: The **definition** of `sizeof` is in units of `char`. Thus `sizeof(char)` is inherently 1. It's like asking "how many meters in a meter?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`size_t` is an unsigned integer type guaranteed to support the longest object for the platform you use. It is also the result of the `sizeof` operator.
`sizeof` returns the size of the type in bytes.
So in your context of question in both cases you pass a `size_t` to `malloc`

Answer (score 2):

It does not literally return a value of type size_t since size_t is not a concrete type in itself, but rather a typedef to an unspecified built-in type. Typedef identifiers (such as size_t) are completely equivalent to their respective underlying types (and are converted thereto at compile time). If size_t is defined as an unsigned int on your platform, then sizeof returns an unsigned int when it is compiled on your system. size_t is just a handy way of maintaining portability and only needs to be included in stddef.h if you are using it explicitly by name.

*This answer is a copy of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739727/c-why-isnt-size-t-a-c-keyword/739753#739753); it was originally written by user Volte.*

Answer (score 2):

That's like asking if there are performance differences between the literal `42` and the type `int`; they're different things.

You use `sizeof(T)` to get the number of bytes a T object uses.  This is mainly useful for `malloc`/`calloc`/`realloc`.

You use `size_t` as the type to store that number.

```
size_t datalen = N * sizeof(char);
char* pBuf = malloc(datalen);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the usefulness is neither particularly apparent nor compelling, and the question and code are flawed - what if the type were to change? `datalen = N` would be an inadequate size.  There is a better idiom which makes better use of sizeof; sizeof(char) is pointless because by definition it is 1 (though CHAR_BIT need not be 8)

If the data type of the dynamic array were to change, and you allocated in blocks of sizeof(object) rather than sizeof(type) then your code becomes more easily maintainable.

e.g.

```
char* data = malloc(sizeof(*data) * N ) ;
```

then if you later decide that data should be int for example then:

```
int* data = malloc(sizeof(*data) * N ) ;
```

only one change instead of two (or many more every where else the size is needed).  This is especially useful for structures and user defined types:

```
tSomeType* data = malloc(sizeof(*data) * N ) ;
```

where you might be changing the sizeof the type by adding or removing members for example.