# When do you need 'int' in C++?

Tags: c++, int

*I do realize the title may sound silly at first, but please, bear with me for a moment. :)*

Ever since I've started using `size_t` and `ptrdiff_t`, I haven't had a use for `int`, as far back as I can remember.

The only integer data types I remember using recently fall into one of these categories:

1. (Unsigned) integers associated with an index into some in-memory data structure (e.g. `vector`).
   Almost always, the most appropriate type for this is `size_t` (or `...::size_type`, if you're going the extra mile).
   Even if the integer doesn't *actually* represent an index, often times it's still *associated* with some index, so `size_t` is still appropriate.
2. Signed versions of `size_t`. In many cases, the most suitable type for this seems to be `ptrdiff_t`, because often times when you need this, you're working with iterators -- and hence `size_t` and `ptrdiff_t` are both appropriate for them.
3. `long`. I occasionally need this for `_InterlockedIncrement` (reference counting).
4. (`unsigned`) `long long`, used for holding file sizes.
5. `unsigned int` or `unsigned long`, useful for "counting" purposes (e.g. every 1 million iterations, update the UI).
6. `unsigned char` for raw byte-level access to memory.
   (Side note: I never found a use for `signed char` either.)
7. `intptr_t` and `uintptr_t` for occasionally storing operating system handles, pointers, etc.

One particular aspect of `int` that's important is that you shouldn't overflow it (since it's undefined behavior), so you can't even use it reliably for counting -- especially if your compiler defines it to be 16 bits.

So when, then, should you use `int` (aside from when a dependency of yours already requires it)?
Is there any real use for it nowadays, at least in newly written, portable code?

Comment: @KarthikT: Looping over what, for example? The loop counters I've used are often looping over ranges in data structures, for which `size_t` or `ptrdiff_t` make much more sense.

Comment: When defining `operator++(int)`? :)

Comment: @Yuushi recursive reason ftw!

Comment: @Yuushi: Haha... touché.

Comment: Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739727/c-why-isnt-size-t-a-c-keyword#739753

TL;DR:
int is a built-in type, size_t is a define, int can represent negative numbers, which is useful for ... math? Seriously.

Comment: @Mehrdad In all seriousness, it's a good question, and something that probably doesn't ever really get asked.

Comment: @KSchmidt Whatever it gets compiled to, it's still an *unsigned* type.

Comment: @Yuushi I didn't say anything to the contrary of that. But 'signed versions of size_t' doesn't make any sense at all. This question doesn't really make sense either - of course signed values are useful! When you are doing math and you need to represent signed values, like x/y positions, etc

Comment: @KSchmidt: A "signed version of `size_t`" make all the sense in the world to me. For example, think about when you want to say `process(str.begin(), str.begin() + str.size() / 2);`, and the compiler gives you a warning for using an unsigned data type (`size_t`) with an iterator. Isn't what you need *precisely* to cast `str.size()` to `ptrdiff_t`, i.e. a "signed version of `size_t`"?

Comment: @KSchmidt: Isn't that just an implementation detail, and only done because it was handier that way? It's not like you *care* about what type is representing `ptrdiff_t` when you declare a variable of type `ptrdiff_t`... that's irrelevant to your code. For all I know, it could be a wrapper around `__int32`, and it wouldn't matter anyway because what matters is the semantics, not the name. And `int` doesn't convey the semantics you need. So the question is, when would *use* `int` itself?

Comment: @Mehrdad Handier? Int is a core building block variable type in the language. short and long are just int with a different size. Int is WORD size, so it's probably 'generally' the most optimal numerical representation type that is signed.

Comment: @KSchmidt I doubt that `size_t` and `ptrdiff_t` are typedef'ed to `(unsigned) int` in most implementations. `long`, yes (except on 64-bit Windows).

Comment: @KSchmidt So `_PTRDIFF_T` is the type of (surprise) the difference of pointers, and `_SIZE_T` is the type `sizeof` returns. If you have a 64-bit system (and that's not unlikely for OSX), print out the sizes of `int`, `long`, `size_t` and `ptrdiff_t`. The probability is large that three of those types have size 8, and `int` has size 4.

Comment: @DanielFischer For **64-bit applications** you are correct, but they are all the same size for 32-bit applications. 

So it's a 32-bit signed type for 64-bit applications - useful when you have a bunch of signed values but want to save memory, no?

Comment: @KSchmidt I'm not questioning the usefulness of a signed 32-bit integer type. I'm questioning your assertion in a comment above that `size_t/ptrdiff_t` are typedef'ed to `(unsigned) int` in most implementations. They are not on most 64-bit platforms, and even on my 32-bit platforms, they were typedef'ed to `(unsigned) long` in all compilers I used.

Comment: Removed my erroneous comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a good use case myself:

`int` is the perfect candidate for storing *integer logarithms*, such as the zoom level on a map.

`short` usually doesn't have enough precision for this (the rotation of a smooth mouse wheel can be very precise), and `long` is usually more precision than we need.
We definitely need negative values, so we shouldn't be using unsigned types. Hence `int` fits the bill.

Answer (score 9):

How about the most important reason of all - **readability**. (and simple math)

```
long weeklyHours = daysWorked * hoursPerDay;
```

*"Okay... but then again, how much can a human actually work per week that we need a `long`"*

```
size_t weeklyHours = daysWorked * hoursPerDay;
```

*"Wait... are we using `weeklyHours` to iterate over a vector?"*

```
unsigned int weeklyHours = daysWorked * hoursPerDay;
```

*"Clear enough."* - possible source for errors if either can be negative (part of the logic - it could be a way to account for time off or leave, not important)

```
int weeklyHours = daysWorked * hoursPerDay;
```

*"Okay, simple enough. I get what this is doing."*

Comment: I don't get it, shouldn't this be using `unsigned int`? Why allow for negatives when there should be none in your code?

Comment: I'd say `unsigned weeklyHours = daysWorked * hoursPerDay;` looks the most readable to me, but I can see this might be argued either way, so +1. Hoping for something more convincing though. ;)

Comment: @Mehrdad while I know the advantages of using `unsigned`, it personally only makes me think about overflowing / bit operations.

Comment: Haha... it's the opposite with me. The first thing I think of when seeing `int` is, omg, can this overflow?! And the second thing I think of is, when is it negative??

Comment: @Mehrdad I agree with Luchian, unsigned values overflow and you will have no idea it happened - if your unsigned value is 0, and you subtract at least 1, boom it's some huge number. For most usage, int has enough value range representation, and doesn't have that 'oops I subtracted by one and now I have a giant number' issue.

Comment: @Mehrdad: in general usage, an `int` might overflow where an `unsigned` would have been safe is when only extra values from about 2^31...2^32 are needed... that's much rarer than generating (even if only temporaries in an expression) values on the "wrong" side of 0.

Answer (score 6):

Luchian has some excellent readability points, to which I'll add some technical ones:

- the compiler's expected to pick a size for `int` that's efficient to deal with, whereas `long` might not be (risks more CPU cycles per operation, more bytes of machine code, more registers needed etc.)
- using signed types can eliminate some errors, such as:

  - `abs(a - b)` looks right mathematically but doesn't give the intuitive result when `b` > `a` and they're unsigned
  - `int second_delta = (x.seconds - y.seconds) + (x.minutes - y.minutes) * 60;`
  - `if (pending - completed > 1) kick_off_threads()`
- when needing an integral sentinel value `-1` is often used: for unsigned types this will be converted to the largest possible value, but that can lead to misunderstandings and coding errors (e.g. `if (x >= 0)` test for non-sentinel)

Also, there's a lot of scope for implicit conversions between signed and unsigned integers - it's important to understand that unsigned types rarely help enforce a "non-negative" invariant: if that's part of the appeal, you're better off writing a class with constructor and operators enforcing the invariant.

On the readability side, `int` denotes a general need for a number that clearly spans the problem domain - it may be excessive but it's known cheap in machine code ops and CPU cycles so is the go-to type for general integral storage.  If you start using say `unsigned char` to store someone's age - not only does it not play well with `operator<<(std::ostream&...)`, but it begs questions like "was there some need to conserve memory here?" (especially confusing for stack-based variables), "is there some intention to treat this as binary data for I/O or IPC purposes?", or even "is it a known single-digit age stored in ASCII?".  If something's likely to end up in a register anyway, `int` is a natural sizing.

Comment: +1 for `abs(a-b)`. I encountered something similar as a bug once. Took me quite some time before I figured out what was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you were implementing a program for a bank account. If you withdraw too much (which some accounts allow you to, with a penalty), then you will need to represent a negative value some way.

Comment: IMO bank accounts should be using `long long`'s, given for example the current US budget and all. =P

Comment: @LuchianGrigore What is the issue about then? One single signed variable type? That tons of #define'd types are based off of, but nobody has a problem with those? Totally confusing.

Comment: @KSchmidt yes, I think so. The op gives `long` as an alternative, which is signed.